# why dot is used in angular app module like this export default angular.module('myapp.report.edit', [])

Tags: angularjs

When I go through my code I got stuckup here and not understanding why this dot is used in angular module app name and what purpose we use it.

My code is like this,

export default angular.module('**myapp.report.edit**', [])

Comment: there is no functional purpose for it. They are used to indicated _sub_ modules. E.g. if you already have `'myapp'` module with `'report'` sub-module, which also has `'edit'` sub-module

Comment: Oh. thanks Aleksey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like @Aleksey Solovey said, there's no functional purpose for it. They are just to differentiate between the different modules of your app. 
For example, Lets say I defined my angular app in a given format:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.components', 'app.controllers']);
```

Now, just for my sake of clarification, I would use `app.controller` to write my controllers, like this:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){});
```

Similarly, if I want to write services, I would use my defined module i.e, `app.services`

```
angular.module('app.services', [])
      .service('$fileToBase64', function () {..})
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks @shaheryar.Akram

Comment: Glad to be of help :)